# Is mentioning someone's @username in an answer supposed to send them a notification?

Tags: discussion, users

Quite a few times I've noticed people mentioning someone's username using the @username format in answers where they reference someone else's answer. I always assumed that this worked the same way as mentioning a username in a comment, however today I happened to check back on one of my answers and noticed that someone had tried to ping me in this way by referencing my username in another answer to the same question, and yet I had not received an inbox notification.

Is this a bug or just expected behaviour? Certainly lots of people appear to *think* that they can ping other users in this way.

Or is it just a convention to always use an @ symbol in front of someone's username like some kind of honorific even when it doesn't have a functional purpose?

Comment: It is not a bug, using @username in an answer will not notify the user.

Comment: Read [How do comment replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: Poor [@username](https://www.google.de/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%2Fusers+username), she's getting thousands of notifications every day…

Comment: i don't think that kinda feature is needed here anyway. this is not a social network

Comment: *Certainly lots of people appear to think that they can ping other users in this way.* [citation needed].

Comment: @astro but... *discussion leading to system-generated "you should go to chat"*

Comment: Try `@chuck`. He *will* get noticed.

Comment: It very much is a social network mixed with a code repository and advertising space.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Mentioning someone's username via @username in an answer is not supposed to send them a notification. This is because an answer is not supposed to notify someone; that's what comments are for.

And as far as why people use that in answers, there are many different usernames (and some can be quite confusing to be recognized as a username), so adding the @ before a name indicates it is a username. Other than that, it is also a common practice to do so (and nothing wrong with it).

It's mostly used when they are referring to another person's post; it's not really for notifying them.

Comment: "This is because an answer is not supposed to notify someone" -- pity.

Comment: @PeterSchneider , If answer's started to work like comments and notify people when their username is mentioned, then many users like Mr Jon Skeet ( not using @ here ) would find the number of notifications they get really troublesome.

Comment: Got a point there. Otoh, that could easily be handled with an opt-out option, possibly with a blacklist and whitelist (Jon would probably still want to get a notification when Eric comments, but not when I do.)

Comment: Here's a thought @Peter-ReinstateMonica.  Should Monica be notified too every time you get a notification?  :-)

Comment: @JChen___, Here

Answer (score 43):

No, using `@username` doesn't work in answers.

It's just text, no notification is sent. Call it a convention, if you will.

Comment: In another community in which I've been active, the convention is to use bold for another user's **moniker** (did I just mention Monica again?), which I have been doing here, generally. But I think the [Nathan Link Convention](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291764/is-mentioning-someones-username-in-an-answer-supposed-to-send-them-a-notificat/291960#291960) is cooler, so I think I'll be using that more often.

Answer (score 20):

Using @username anywhere besides in a comment does not send a notification. I suspect using @ before usernames in answers and questions starts where people see this usage in comments and try using it elsewhere, then people keep doing it out of habit even after they know it doesn't notify anybody.

If you want to refer to a user, then link to the user's profile page. Since usernames can change, duplicates are allowed, and the comment notification system allows partial usernames, using the @ relies on context to figure out who you're talking about. In comments this is fine because the number of participants is restricted, but in references across posts it becomes less clear. Using a link gives an easy way to refer to a user unambiguously.

Especially in the context you mention in the question, referring to a specific answer from another answer, it would be a lot better to link to that answer directly. The link would eliminate the searching around required when reading a mention of a post by a user and trying to track it down.

Comment: Yeah, but @Nathan's answer [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291960/171318) looks better than Nathan's answer [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291960/171318). Isn't it? (And your username isn't something like hsdrfu324)

Comment: Why are you linking "here" @hek2mgl? Just write [Nathan's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291960/458741), and it's all a lot clearer.

Comment: @Ben I really like your suggestion! This is even useful in comments since you are allowed to address only a single user. Through the text color of the link - which differs from the text body - it is pretty clear that I refer to another user's post. Cool! Will keep that in mind! :)

Comment: @Ben Where does the "/458741" in the "Nathan's answer" link come from? This link also works to get to Nathans answer: "http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291960/".  Oh! I see it is your user id number. Follow up: why add that?

Comment: @Chris: maybe so they can track who linked to what so they can award badges like announcer?